# The specified content type was not found - Error 611 - NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm following the step by step [tutorial](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3) of NativeScript but I'm facing the following issue:

When I try to make a post request through my Angular service I get the following error:

```
JS: {"message":"The specified content type was not found.","errorCode":611}
```

My code looks pretty much the same as the one in the official docs from NativeScript:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { User } from './user';
import { Config } from '../config';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    register(user: User): Observable<Response> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const url = `${Config.apiUrl}/Users`;
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            Username: user.email,
            Email: user.email,
            Password: user.password
        });

        return this._http.post(url, body, { headers })
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }

    handleErrors(error: Response) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

Component class:

```
signUp() {
  this._user.register(this.user).subscribe(
    () => {
      alert('Your account has been successfully created.');
      this.toggleDisplay();
    },
    () => {
      // errors here...
      alert('Unfortunately we were unable to create your account.');
    }
  );
}
```

Tested under Android and IOs, both throws the same error.

Isn't `application/json` the expected `Content-Type` in this case? 
If I change the type I get another error saying that the type is missing or is invalid.

Can someone please point out what am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `Config.apiUrl`?

Comment: It points to `https://api.everlive.com/v1/GWfRtXi1Lwt4jcqK/`, i'm gonna check if the problem is the concatenation of the `/` symbol at the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, thank you @anthares